# .NET Core Invalid Object Name 'ApplicationUsers' When logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my login function:

```
LoginViewModel lvm = new LoginViewModel
{
    UserName = Input.UserName,
    Password = Input.Password,
    RememberMe = Input.RememberMe
};
var valid = accountsData.Authenticate(lvm);
if (valid != null)
{
    var avm = applicationUsersData.GetByUsername(Input.UserName);
    var user = applicationUsersData.Get(avm.Id);
    var roles = userRolesData.GetUserRoles(user.Id);
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.UserName, user.UserName));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.Email, user.Email));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.PhoneNumber, user.PhoneNumber));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.FirstName, user.FirstName));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.LastName, user.LastName));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.Id, user.Id));
    foreach (var item in roles)
    {
        var currentItem = new UserRoleDetailsViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            ApplicationId = item.ApplicationId,
            ApplicationName = item.ApplicationName
        };
        var convertedItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentItem);
        claims.Add(new Claim(ManagementStudio.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.Roles, convertedItem));
    }
    await _customClaimsCookieSignInHelper.SignInUserAsync(user, Input.RememberMe, claims);
    activityLogger.Log(HttpContext, user.Id, configuration[DSCASGlobals.DS_Name], configuration[DSCASGlobals.DS_Id], Input.UserName + " logged in");
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

accountsData.Authenticate is located in a referenced dll assembly called ManagementStudio.Data and looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ApplicationUsers Authenticate(LoginViewModel Input)
{
    PasswordHasher<ApplicationUsers> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUsers>();
    ApplicationUsers user = new ApplicationUsers();
    try
    {
        user = dbContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == Input.UserName);
        if(user != null)
        {
            if (passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user,user.PasswordHash,Input.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            {
                return user;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, LoggingGlobals.Error);
        return null;
    }
    return user;
}
```

When I run the application and login, I get this error:

> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
>   context type 'ManagementStudio.Data.Models.ManagementStudioDbContext'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'ApplicationUsers'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean
>   asyncWrite, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext
>   _, Boolean buffer) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1
>   results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos,
>   IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext() at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Boolean& found) at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.b__0(QueryContext
>   qc) ClientConnectionId:7c19efa6-d951-4139-8135-8dbcd5050c20 Error
>   Number:208,State:1,Class:16

ApplicationUsers is my IdentityUser and is located in ManagementStudio.Data.Models. DocumentStudio references it.

```
public class ApplicationUsers : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    private DateTime createdOn = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (createdOn == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : createdOn;
        }
        set
        {
            createdOn = value;
        }
    }
    private DateTime updatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (updatedOn == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : updatedOn;
        }
        set
        {
            updatedOn = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

My full DBSet

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
public DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>> IdentityUserRole { get; set; }
public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>> IdentityUserClaim { get; set; }
public DbSet<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
public DbSet<ApiAccess> ApiAccess { get; set; }
public DbSet<EventLogs> EventLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<ActivityLogs> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<CommunicationLogs> CommunicationLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<UploadLogs> UploadLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<Repositories> Repositories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Emails> Emails { get; set; }
public DbSet<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
public DbSet<Announcements> Announcements { get; set; }
public DbSet<AnnouncementAttachments> AnnouncementAttachments { get; set; }
```

List of Models:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `ApplicationUsers` (plural) be `ApplicationUser` (singular) for the object model

Comment: The object model itself is called ApplicationUsers. I should rename it but i dont think thats an issue for now.

Comment: This error means that EF is translating your LINQ into a sql statement that uses ApplicationUsers object(db table) does not exist in database . Does table exist for the object? and also verify your database connection string as well.

Comment: ApplicationUsers exists as ManagementStudio.ApplicationUsers. Theres a schema attached to it.

Comment: Is it possible to set the Schema for the referenced assembly?

Comment: decorate your class with [TableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) - there is an optional parameter for schema name (or use fluent api `.ToTable(..)` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in comments your table name for `ApplicationUsers` class is `ManagementStudio.ApplicationUsers`. You need to tell EF your schema name, because it use `dbo` by default. There is a lot of ways to do this:

Use [TableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute):

```
[Table("ApplicationUsers", Schema = "ManagementStudio")]
public class ApplicationUsers : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Use fluent API:

```
public class ManagementStudioDbContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .ToTable("ApplicationUsers", schema: "ManagementStudio");
    }
}
```

Set default schema name with fluent API:

```
public class ManagementStudioDbContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyCustomSchema");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with using IdentityDbContext is that ill get a whole bunch of AspNet tables though.

Comment: @JianYA, this will work with a common `DbContext` also.

Comment: Right now my ManagementStudioDbContext just extends DbContext. However, when I set it to that, I get this error: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserClaim<string>' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

Comment: I added my list of dbsets and models at the bottom of my question

Comment: With `IdentityDbContext`, when you overriding `OnModelCreating` - you must call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` first

Comment: But I guess your solution solved my issue. Ill start a new question for the second issue.